# How to correctly get the temperature of any CPU in Linux?

Tags: linux, cpu, temperature

### What I need?

I am creating a software and I need to obtain the temperature of any CPU (x86_64), either through reading files, executing some api written in C or executing some command with or without privileges in GNU/Linux systems.

### Where have I searched?

I've searched a lot on the internet, even some stackoverflow posts with the same questions, but none of them refer to general getting the temperature of any cpu, they all offer custom solutions for obsolete systems or some specific cpu models, but I don't find any software that can correctly deliver the CPU temperature.

### Where is the problem?

- `lm_sensors`: It does not provide temperature indicators for a CPU, it only reads ids with values but it is not able to indicate which of all the ids corresponds to a CPU, for example, in AMD Ryzen 7 it is `k10temp-pci-00c3`. How can I tell if `k10temp-pci-00c3` belongs to a CPU and not something else from programming code?. As a user you have to guess using common sense, but my software can't guess. Same issue using `hardinfo` and `xsensors`.
- `cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp`: Not all hardware uses this path to set temperature, for example AMD Ryzen 7 does not use these paths, also Radeon RX 6800 XT uses this path, so most software that get temperature from this path will be showing the temperature of the GPU and not the CPU, like as `Conky` and `CPU-X`.
- `acpi`: It does not display any temperature related information when using an AMD CPU.

Comment: With intel CPU `lm_sensors` gives you e.g. `coretemp-isa-0000`. Each single core `temp` (Core 0: ... Core n) is given.  It is open source so you can see the code (`xsensors` is an X11 interface to `lm_sensors`). Maybe you can find something interesting [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/lm_sensors). However, if you rely on `lm_sensors` (`sensors -u`), you will need to deal with its output but not with the different paths below...

Comment: To get some sensor info, you may have to boot with `acpi_enforce_resources=lax` against the kernel command line. But then again may be not. Depends how broken things are.

Comment: Thanks @Bib but can not force users to modify the kernel only for use my application :(

Comment: Well, I suggest you try it on your own system to see if that is a cause. If it is, then you will have to look for another cure, which I doubt you will find.